# Search first sheet column's values into other sheet's column

Tags: python, nlp

I have two excel sheets named Driver and Call_transcript.

Driver sheet contains T1, T2, T3, T3_Nomencleture, keyword columns and Call_transcript sheet contains two Contact_ID and transcript_text columns.
Call_transcript contains multiple contact_ID and respective transcript_text column(conversation between agent and customer)

I want to check if the values of Keyword column of the "Driver" sheet are present in transcript_text column or not. If it is present, print T3, T3_Nomencleture & Keyword column's value.
Every contact_ID is unique and check should happen for one contact_ID at a time and return the result.

In simple words, I need to predict the correct call driver name for each contact_ID.
My approach to this problem is to use the fuzzy logic method. I also thought of applying the dictionary key-based search method. But that seems to be too long and I might not get good accuracy also.

Please help me to figure out what could be the best solution/approach to this problem.

Comment: Please provide a copy/pasteable [mre], please try to focus your problem of the most relevant element. If your question contains multiple steps and subquests, ask them seperately. Please avoid pictures of data. Please show your current appraoch (short) and where the problem occured.

Comment: @Andreas, Sure let me try to break this further. Also, I have removed the data pictures.  On an overview level, can you please suggest if fuzzy logic is the good approach here?

Comment: That depends, look at this and provide sample data (e.g. in a pandas dataframe) for df1 and df2 show your current appraoch and and where a problem or inefficency appeared. Reduce your question, it seems to me irrelevant if the data comes from excel or something else. If you just want to check if a string is in another string you can do `'abcde'.contains('bcd')`